# Jekyll Front Matter Path Doesn't Work

Tags: jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I have two sections of my site, **intro** and **core**, that I want to have two different navigation bars.

Here is my **navigation.yml**

```
main:
  - title: "Intro"
    url: /intro/intro

  - title: "Core"
    url: /core/core-1

intro:
  - title: Introduction
    children: 
      - title: Intro
        url: /intro/welcome

core: 
  - title: Core
    children:
      - title: Core
        url: /core/core-1
```

Here is the relevant part of **_config.yml**

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "intro"
      type: pages
    values:
      layout: single
      classes: wide
      sidebar:
        nav: "intro" 
  - scope:
      path: "core"
      type: pages
    values:
      layout: single
      classes: wide
      sidebar:
        nav: "core"
```

My directory structure is:

```
/_pages/intro/welcome.md
/_pages/core/core-1.md
```

This results in **neither navigation is displayed.** What's going on here?

Comment: I think you need to develop an `_include` file which iterates through your navigation array. If you still have issues, please show us the layout file(s).

Answer (score 1):

Michael Rose answered this question on his github issues page [here](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/issues/1795).

It's not working because my paths were wrong. To make this work, I had to add _pages/ before the folder names.

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: _pages/intro
      type: pages
    values:
      layout: single
      classes: wide
      sidebar:
        nav: "intro" 
  - scope:
      path: _pages/core
      type: pages
    values:
      layout: single
      classes: wide
      sidebar:
        nav: "core"
```